# Exclude multiple non-consecutive IP addresses from Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics, ip

I have over 100 satellite offices with static IPs that I need to exclude from my Google Analytics report. The limit seems to be 255 characters which is nowhere near enough. They are not consecutive or in blocks either so not easy to implement a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worst case is that you create a filter for each IP address. I don't believe there is a limit to the number of filters you can create for a single profile. Best is if you can find some sort of grouping in the IPs and combine in your regexes. Alternatively, and this may be less ideal, is that if you know that traffic will ONLY come from certain IPs, then you can use an include filter instead.

Comment: Nyuen, one question on creating filters for each IP. Will that mean that I get data filtered by just the one IP, rather than the whole collection?

Comment: No, if you have set up multiple filters, GA will go down the list applying them sequentially. So if you had IP address 100.100.100.3 coming in, and your first filter filters out 100.100.100.1 and your second filter filters out 100.100.100.2, then those two would not apply until you get to the third filter, which would filter out 100.100.100.3.